# Stuck with Target audience and content in google play console

Tags: android, app-store, google-play-console

[image]

I am stuck with the above screen while I am going to upload my next release.
My app targets the users under the age of 13 also, and I am not able to select this child age group,

Can anyone have an idea how I can get those age group clickable? As I am not able to find any solution for such case in google play console's documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding Privacy policy can solve your issue.

If you see you have disabled option to enter privacy policy, you can go with all available target age group option first.

Once you will complete section of 'App content', you will see that you will now able to add privacy policy link in 'Store listing' section. Add privacy policy URL and go to 'App Content' section again.

Start again app content form and you will see all age group options enabled.

Comment: Yes, I tried and worked, It actually did the trick, thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

As screenshot says ,you have to add privacy policy for age group below 13. So first add this from your store listing then you will be able to select those age group.

Comment: It showing disabled privacy policy input as well on publish screen.

Comment: Try adding all other infomation apart from user audience and apk or .aab don't publish the app. Then see if it is enabled

Comment: you will find it on store presence-> store listing -> then @ bottom privacy policy. add privacy policy url there. before you have to upload your apk or aab

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding privacy policy under tab Store listing on Publish console

Comment: It showing disabled privacy policy input as well on publish screen.